# How to do bulk changes in an audited table?

Tags: database, architecture, auditing, audit-trail

I've got a system where all changes to business objects have to be audited.  So an entity `MyEntity` has a `Number` property, and when you change this field, the system leaves the original record alone, and makes another record with the new number value, and marks the original record *archived*.  `Number` is **not** the primary key.  There's also a `Version` field to track each version of the entity, and an `Id` field to track object identity across multiple versions.  So far so good.

If you **delete** the entity, the system doesn't delete the record, but just marks it as *deleted*.  So far so good.

Here's the problem.  Now the client has a bunch of entities in a list, and there can be gaps:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 5
Item 6
...
Item 10
```

They want to be able to do two new things:

1. **Insert** an item with number 5, and shift all the subsequent items up a number (5 --> 6, 6--> 7 etc)
2. **Collapse gaps** in the items, e.g., renumber 5 --> 4, and shift all subsequent items down a number.

This seems really nasty to me, because normally any change to a number would need to be audited, so I can't just change all the numbers in bulk like that.  (And it's even more complex still, because each change needs to be approved by a supervisor, and changes can be restored to a previous audit state.)

Even worse, item 4 might exist, but be missing because it's in an archived state.  If you want to collapse subsequent items, what should happen to the existing archived item?  I can't see a reasonable way to handle these situations while auditing them, and allowing for approvals and restore.  Anyone know how to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never really solved this problem in a fully satisfying way, but we handled this by implementing a special mode, available only to the super admin, where auditing is disabled for this kind of identity changing operation, on the grounds that the `Number`, while not a primary key, is an essential user key, and if you change it, you're changing the object identity to a new thing, which starts with a clean slate.  Not ideal, but a reasonable compromise.

Answer (score 0):

> I've got a system where all changes to business objects have to be
>   audited.

Try to suggest an exception to this rule for **Number** property. If this property is also used for other reasons and has to be audit anyway, then you could suggest a new field **OrderByNumber** and have it free of audit requirement.

If your argument faces resistance, I would try to rename Number or OrderByNumber to something ridiculous but obvious. It will make people smile and they will see the point: **NotABusinessConcernNumberButUIElementNumberUsedForVisualOrdering**.

If there is no way you could have an exception to audit rules for your business objects, then you would have to create a different layer of UI/presentation objects and keep a mapping between the two.